# How can I send a success message back to the client after I use findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to send a message back to the client to tell the user wether the account is found or not. I can obviously use the writehead and .end() methods outside of the promise. But I am not sure how to do that within an asynchronous routine such as collection.findOne.

The following code res.end("SUCCESS") returns nothing into this.responseText. So how can I go about sending back SUCCESS to the client after the finding the account info?

```
collection.findOne(postData)
    .then(result => {
        if(result) {
            console.log(`Successfully found document: ${result}.`);

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            console.log("No document matches the provided query.");
        }
        return result;
    }).catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find document: ${err}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
collection.find(postData).toArray((err, mongoRes) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    confirmationStatus: false
                })
            } else {
                if (mongoRes.length === 0) {
                    res.send({
                        confirmationStatus: false
                    })
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        confirmationStatus: true
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```